# How to make part of a div transparent to show what's underneath?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to make a ui similar to this image [image]

I don't know how to make the center of the top div circular and transparent as it is in the image provided..

I've thought of using canvas but after searching I found nothing, but creating circular canvas only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ::after element to provide the circle, just use CSS variables to provide a constant image.

```js
function applyZoom() {
  const zoomValue = document.getElementById('sizeinput').value;
  const zoom = '--zoom:' + zoomValue + ";"
  document.getElementById('myavatar').setAttribute('style', zoom);
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  --image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/46/300/300');
  --size: 400px;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  width:400px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-image:  linear-gradient(rgba(56, 76, 111, 0.5), rgba(56, 76, 111, 0.5)), var(--image);
   
}

.mydiv, .mydiv::after {
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(var(--zoom) * var(--size)) calc(var(--zoom) * var(--size));
}

.mydiv::after {
  display:block;
  content:"";
  width:200px;
  border:2px solid white;
  border-radius:100vh;
  background-image: var(--image);
}
```

```html
<div class='mydiv' id='myavatar' style='--zoom: 1;'>
</div>
<br>
<input id='sizeinput'><button onclick='applyZoom()'>Zoom</button>
```

**Edited to add**
In the comment, there's a need to zoom the image. Just using the ::after pseudo elemnt, the overlay shading sizes with the image. This isn't a problem for zooms greater than 1 but if it's less than 1, it breaks. This can be solved by using the 'before' element and z-index as follows:

```js
function applyZoom() {
  const circleWidth = 200;
  const zoomValue = document.getElementById('sizeinput').value;
  document.getElementById('zoomText').textContent = zoomValue;
  
  const zoom = '--zoom:' + zoomValue + ";"
  const element = document.getElementById('myavatar');
  
  const containerSize = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--size"));
  const resizedImageSize = containerSize * zoomValue;
  
  if(resizedImageSize >= circleWidth) {
    element.setAttribute('style', zoom);
    }
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  --image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/46/300/300');
  --size: 400px;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  width:400px;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-image:  var(--image);
}

.mydiv, .mydiv::after {
  aspect-ratio:1;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(var(--zoom) * var(--size)) calc(var(--zoom) * var(--size));
}

.mydiv::before {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  inset: 0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: rgba(56, 76, 111, 0.8);
}

.mydiv::after {
  display:block;
  content:"";
  width:200px;
  border:2px solid white;
  border-radius:100vh;
  background-image: var(--image);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='mydiv' id='myavatar' style='--zoom: 1;'>
</div>
<br>
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="0.1" id="sizeinput" oninput='applyZoom()'>
Zoom: <span id='zoomText'></span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I making it as  a component so that the user can zoom in  and out on his avatar so to crop it with javascript.
Is there a way to make it possible using your technique ?!

Comment: Sure. I've added a bit of javascript to show you how to do this.

Comment: Thank you @Adam, this is 70% percent of what I was looking for, I'll have to firstly figure out how to stop the zoom out if the whole picture is inside the circle, secondly crop the part zoomed in, if you could help with these two issues I would be very grateful and thanks again.

Comment: Use getComputedValue to get the sizes of each to limit the zoom. I've added an example to the last code snippet

Answer (score 1):

This snippet makes use of the `mask-box-image` property

```css
.masking{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-mask-box-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, gray 60%, rgba(140, 140, 140, 0.3) 60%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://music.columbia.edu/sites/default/files/styles/page_image_square/public/images/stylianos_dimou_profile-alt.jpg?itok=mOF8wxnL" class="masking">
```

[Source](https://linuxhint.com/masking-css/#:%7E:text=of%20an%20ellipse.-,Example%203,-Suppose%20you%20want)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on firefox. :-(

Comment: thanks @Inglan, How can i change the background color?

Comment: Thanks @Inglan, I making it as  a component so that the user can zoom in  and out on his avatar so to crop it with javascript.
Is there a way to make it possible using your technique ?!

Answer (score 1):

What about making it two distinct elements?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.background, .foreground {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/500") 50% 50%/500px 500px;
}

.background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}
.background::after {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.foreground {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="foreground"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Micheal, I making it as  a component so that user can zoom in  and out on his avatar so that I can crop it with javascript.
Is there a way to make it possible using your technique ?!